# CSS arrange two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML:

```
<div className={`page-header-profile-photo-container`}>
    <div className="user-picture">
    </div>
    <div className="user-name">
       <p>Sample GmbhH</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
  .page-header-profile-photo-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 130px;
    width: 200px;

  }
  .user-picture {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #787567;
  }
  .user-name{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;

  }
```

This renders like following:

[image]

I want to have some space between circular div and text. page-header-profile-photo-container's position has to be absolute.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `display: inline-block` on your `.user_name class` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all correct your syntax like `className` to `class` and try the following code. No need to `position:absolute` in `user-name` class

```css
  .page-header-profile-photo-container{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 130px;

  }
  .user-picture {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #787567;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .user-name{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class=page-header-profile-photo-container>
    <div class="user-picture">
    </div>
    <div class="user-name">
       <p>Sample GmbhH</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: className because actually I am using React!

Comment: Thanks! I used this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning in user name. Absolute positioning puts an item in a particular position no matter what (doesn't care if it gets overlapped)

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex-box` it will work good for me. Hope this help.

```css
.page-header-profile-photo-container{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: 10%;
    right: 130px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 200px;

  }
  .user-picture {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /*background-color: #787567;*/
  }
  .user-picture img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .user-name{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class=page-header-profile-photo-container>
    <div class="user-picture">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="Profile Picture" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-name">
       <p>Sample GmbhH</p>
    </div>
</div>
```